# Angular view not updating despite variables changed in model

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm making a youtube playlist project with Gooogle OAuth, I met a little issue while handling the authentication process, the variable `isAuthorized` is where I store the user sign-in state, I can see in the console that it's changed to true after user sign in, but it's still false in the View section. I wonder how exactly I solve this?

below is my code for the Model section

```
GoogleAuth: any;
user: any;
isAuthorized = false;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    // Load auth2 library
    gapi.load("client:auth2", this.initClient);
  }

  loadClient = () => {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(this.API_KEY);
    return gapi.client
      // same as "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest"
      .load("youtube", "v3")
      .then(
        () => {
          console.log("GAPI client loaded for API");
        },
        function (err) {
          console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err);
        }
      );
  }

  // Init API client library and set up sign in listeners
  initClient = () => {
    gapi.client
      .init({
        discoveryDocs: this.DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        clientId: this.CLIENT_ID,
        scope: this.SCOPES,
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        this.GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(this.handleSigninStatus);

        // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
        this.handleSigninStatus();
        this.loadClient()
      });
  }

  handleSigninStatus = () => {
    this.user = this.GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
    this.isAuthorized = this.user.hasGrantedScopes(this.SCOPES);
    if (this.isAuthorized) {
      this.loadClient()
      // this.getChannelInfo() //display playlist data
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }
  }

  // Handle login
  handleAuthClick = () => {
    this.GoogleAuth.signIn({ scope: this.SCOPES })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Sign-in successful");
        // this.isLoggedIn = true
        this.getChannelInfo()
      },
        (err: any) => { console.error("Error signing in", { err }) });
  }

  // Handle logout
  handleSignoutClick = () => {
    this.GoogleAuth.signOut();
    this.GoogleAuth.disconnect();
    // gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut().then(() => { this.googleUser = null });
  }
```

and this is my HTML, aka the View section:

```
<mat-toolbar>
      <a href="/">My Application {{isAuthorized}}</a>
      <ng-template [ngIf]="isAuthorized" [ngIfElse]="loggedOut">
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" id="signout-button" (click)="handleSignoutClick()">Log Out</button>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #loggedOut>
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" id="authorize-button" (click)="handleAuthClick()">Log In</button>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-toolbar>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this.GoogleAuth` events operate out of angular's scope/zone you need to bring its callbacks into the angular zone. This way angular's lifecycle events will handle the changes on the data appropriately.

Wrap your event handler function(s) with [ngZone's run](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run) function. This is advisable every time you are modifying an angular monitored variable via events that do not belong to the angular scope/zone:

```js
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone ... 

...

initClient = () => {
    gapi.client
      .init({
        discoveryDocs: this.DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        clientId: this.CLIENT_ID,
        scope: this.SCOPES,
      })
      .then(() => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => { // <-- here
        this.GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        this.GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(this.handleSigninStatus);

        // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
        this.handleSigninStatus();
        this.loadClient()
  });
      });
  }


handleSigninStatus = () => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => { // <-- here
    this.user = this.GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
    this.isAuthorized = this.user.hasGrantedScopes(this.SCOPES);
    if (this.isAuthorized) {
      this.loadClient()
      // this.getChannelInfo() //display playlist data
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }
  });
}
```

The easiest way to bring model modifications into the angular's scope/zone is to wrap them with a ngZone call like this one above.